# 404 on GET request Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-9

I'm working on a project with the new version of Laravel. My other projects are all previous versions. I tried every `artisan clean` method to make everything clear. I checked the server requirements, which are precisely the same as how I run my other Laravel 8 projects. But when I request by Postman my API, it returns a 404 page instead of the actual action.

**Route**

```
GET|HEAD   api/token ... generated::*** › UserController@tokenRequest
```

**api.php**

```
Route::get('token', [UserController::class, 'tokenRequest']);
```

I return a simple response with a token. If there is a PHP error, I'll see it and not return with a 404, which is weird. I had the same problem with my other projects, but it was just a mod_rewrite issue, but I all checked those options. Each is set correctly in the .conf. I use apache on my Ubuntu 20.04 server, like my other projects. The only difference is the Laravel version.

URL that I use:

```
https://example.com/directory/api/token
```

Public directory URL is working perfectly.

```
https://example.com/directory/public
```

**Custom domain .conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.log combined
```

Comment: Can you please try -- https://example.com/directory/public/api/token ?

Comment: Same 404 error sadly @HarshDoshi

Comment: Execute these commands: php artisan optimize and then php artisan config:clear  and then try to access URLs

Comment: I Already did that, but I tried again no good result: still 404 @HarshDoshi

Comment: please share your apache conf code

Comment: @HarshDoshi See result in the description. I edited.

Comment: "Easiest" would be to set up a vhost for every project you're using. The DocumentRoot of Laravel projects should be the project's `public` folder

Comment: @brombeer Every project has his own server, so it doesn't matter. I can change it to the public folder, but I want to use in this way, this doesn't effect the way of getting 404 on a api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually setup vhost for each project and this is how it looks like for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public

<Directory "/var/www/html/example.com/public">
    AllowOverride All
    ReWriteEngine On
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.log combined
```

and this worked for all my laravel apps

Comment: It worked. but not the way of Vhosts but the code you shared worked.